# How do I connect a device to SQL server through a network?

Tags: sql-server, iis, sql-server-ce, rda

I have a laptop with SQL Server and the Compact server agent and IIS running. I'd like to connect a mobile device to another laptop on the same network and be able to access the SQL Server. How do I go about this? I know it's possible with IIS and RDA, but I'm getting the following error:

```
 Error Code: 80072EFF
 Message: A request to send data to the computer running the IIS has failed.
 For more information, see HRESULT.
 Minor Err.: 28037
 Source: Microsoft SQL Server Compact
```

Comment: Start by checking if you have basic Network connectivity from the device!

Comment: Pinging the desktop gives me an error 11010. Is this something wrong with the network or the mobile device config?

Comment: Try changing the ActiveSync configuration (Work Network vs Internet), and ping the desktop IP address and not the machine name

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your accounting for your internet proxy. I had a similar problem and as soon as I unchecked the proxy settings in internet options, the error message went away.

[image]